# How to check the all values are empty or not using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to check all the values are empty or not inside `child tr` tag and update the `parent tr tag` . my table format looks like below :

[image]

As per picture, I need to update the status for `parent tr tag` for the column `Assigned` based on `child tr` tag  `assetID` column .

If any one of `child assetID column values` is empty, I need add `Amber color` to `parent assigned column` .

if all `child assetID column values` empty i need add `Red color to parent tr`
if all filled , then `green color` to `parent tr tag` .

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var val = className = number ='';
    $('.assignedAssetID').each(function() {

      val = $(this).val();
      if( val != '' )
      {
          $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(6) .assig_noti").addClass('assign_complete');
      }else
      {

       $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(6) .assig_noti").addClass('not_assign');
      }

       className = $(this).closest('table').attr('class').split(' ')[0];
       number = parseFloat(className.match(/-*[0-9]+/));

         $('.ParentBundle'+number).each(function() {

          if( val != '' )
          {
              $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(8) .assig_noti").addClass('assign_complete');
          }else
          {

           $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(8) .assig_noti").addClass('not_assign');
          }

        });

    });



});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table>
<tr class="ParentBundle21393114881">
    <td style="display: none">
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="mar">1XPaver 2XRoller</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="25/07/2017" name="est_start_date[]" placeholder="Date Start" class="StartDate form-control date">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="27/07/2017" name="est_off_date[]" placeholder="Date Off" class="OffDate form-control date">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="week_count[]" value="3" placeholder="" class="WeekDayCount21393114881 form-control wdCount">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="nonweek_count[]" value="0" placeholder="" class="WeekEndCount21393114881 form-control weCount">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="row_total[]" id="RowTotal21393114881" value="1140.00" readonly="" class="RowTotal form-control">
    </td>
    <td class="ExtraCheckbox_main">
        <input type="checkbox" name="extra[]" class="js-switch" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="assig_noti"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BundleExpand"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></button>
            <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentModal" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa ficon fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <button type="button" data-code="B21393114881" data-id="1" data-type="bundle" class="btn btn-default DeleteBundleRow"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="ChildBundle21393114881" style="background: rgb(249, 249, 249) !important;">
    <td colspan="9" style="padding: 0!important;">
        <table cellpadding="5" border="0" class="ChildTable21393114881  child_tbl table" width="100%" style="background: #f9f9f9!important;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="20%"></th>
                    <th width="20%">
                        ASSET ID
                    </th>
                    <th width="16%" colspan="2">RATES</th>
                    <th width="10%">
                    </th>
                    <th width="5%">
                    </th>
                    <th width="14%">
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%">
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>                                                                                                                                   Paver
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select style="width:100%" name="assigned_asset[]" class="form-control select2_demo_2 assignedAssetID" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                        <option value="">--Not Assigned --</option>
                        <option value="PV01">PV01</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="week_rate[]" value="150.00" placeholder="" class="Week form-control"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nonweek_rate[]" value="200.00" placeholder="" class="NonWeek form-control"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="450.00" name="rate[]" readonly="" placeholder="" id="ChildRowTotal62" class="ChildRowTotal form-control"></td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="assig_noti not_assign"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 43px;"><input type="hidden" id="comment62" name="comments[]" class="form-control ctext">
                    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentModal" type="button" class="Comment btn btn-default"><i class="fa ficon fa-comment-o" id="fa62" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>                                                                                                                                              Small Roller
            </td>
            <td>
                <select style="width:100%" name="assigned_asset[]" class="form-control select2_demo_2 assignedAssetID " tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <option value="">--Not Assigned --</option>
                    <option value="RL01" selected="">RL01</option>
                    <option value="RL02">RL02</option>
                    <option value="RL03">RL03</option>
                    <option value="RL04">RL04</option>
                    <option value="RL05">RL05</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="week_rate[]" value="110.00" placeholder="" class="Week form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nonweek_rate[]" value="160.00" placeholder="" class="NonWeek form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="330.00" name="rate[]" readonly="" placeholder="" id="ChildRowTotal71" class="ChildRowTotal form-control"></td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="assig_noti"></div>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 43px;"><input type="hidden" id="comment71" name="comments[]" class="form-control ctext">
                <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentModal" type="button" class="Comment btn btn-default"><i class="fa ficon fa-comment-o" id="fa71" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 
             Medium Roller
        </td>
        <td>
            <select style="width:100%" name="assigned_asset[]" class="form-control select2_demo_2 assignedAssetID " tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <option value="">--Not Assigned --</option>
                <option value="MRL01">MRL01</option>
                <option value="MRL02">MRL02</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="week_rate[]" value="120.00" placeholder="" class="Week form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nonweek_rate[]" value="220.00" placeholder="" class="NonWeek form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="360.00" name="rate[]" readonly="" placeholder="" id="ChildRowTotal84" class="ChildRowTotal form-control"></td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="assig_noti"></div>
            </td>
            <td width="15%" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 43px;"><input type="hidden" id="comment84" name="comments[]" class="form-control ctext">
            <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentModal" type="button" class="Comment btn btn-default"><i class="fa ficon fa-comment-o" id="fa84" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But i m not getting how do i check  `assetID` child tr column to satisfy the status of parent tr .

Any suggestions Please.

Comment: check this for checking selectbox but u need to repeat each row and add conditions accordingly https://jsfiddle.net/etn1zgnf/

Comment: @NadeemmnnMohd : I'm trying for that its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

```
code
----

<table id="tbl">
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="tb1"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="tb2"></td>
  <td>
<select class="select" onchange="checkIndex()">
        <option value="1">select</option>
        <option value="2">V2</option>
        <option value="3">V3</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><h1  id="status">
    status
    </h1></td>
</tr>
</table>
    <script>function checkIndex(){ 
    var boolTxtBox=false;
        var selectBoxselectedIndex=$(".select")[0].selectedIndex;
//alert(selectBoxselectedIndex);
        if(selectBoxselectedIndex>0){
             // set the background to green

             var txtboxes =$('#tbl input:text');
             $.each(txtboxes,function(i,v){ 
            if($(v).val().length>0){
                    boolTxtBox=true;
                }
                else{
                    boolTxtBox=false;
                }
             });
             if(boolTxtBox==true){
                $('#status').css({'color':'green'});
             }else{
                $('#status').css({'color':'red'});
             }
        }
        else{
            //set the background to red
            $('#status').css({'color':'red'});
        }
    }</script>
```

working demo [jsFiddle working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/pavx5970/3/)

Comment: note you need to repeat for your table and complete the task

Comment: Okay let me try doing that